# How do I disable update warnings on my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios-appstore

I got a bought app (i.e. not a free one - be it given to me, bought by me or gifted, I don't know). It works great. Then some update for it comes along with many other updates for other apps. I press "update all" and every time this one app gives me a notification that I need to buy it because it's a new major version or whatever. Well, I don't want to do it, it works fine the way it is (probably because I was still in iOS 3.1.3)!

So, how can I just remove the future updates from the list? If there is any way to do it, that is.

<sup>P.S.: Now I upgraded to iOS 4, the app stopped working and I decided to just delete it along with another couple of apps which had a similar issue.</sup>

Comment: that is very interesting - can you give the name of the app that behaves like that? have never seen AppStore giving such warnings, is this the case of the app when you start it saying you need to go and buy it under *another* name? AFAIK in app store once purchased an app, it's updates are always free!

Comment: @Nas I should have said the name before, but I don't think it really matters. I can't recall, it was a GPS info app that brought detailed information about GPS location. Eventually I got a better one and deleted the annoying one. As for the couple of other apps, heck, I don't think I even used them! :P - But I bet this issue was because it was added into my iPhone through my brother iTunes, on his account. He bought it on his account and added to my phone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't get charged for app upgrades on iOS. You only get notification for free updates.

Comment: Maybe it has to do with the fact this app was purchased by someone and given to me?

Comment: Granted, I've never gifted or received a gifted app, but I don't think so. Even paid apps that I delete if I "purchase" them again later it says "you already bought this, so it's free". iOS won't prompt you for any upgrades that you have to pay for.

Comment: a gifted app is linked to the account of the person it was given to after they use the redeem code in the email that is sent to them from the person giving the gift.

it sounds like the app was put on your phone from another person's computer and the app was purchased by them and therefore linked to their account.

Comment: @Ryan, yes. I never said it was a "gifted app". It was put on my phone from another computer and purchased by them, and it is linked to their account. So you think that's the issue?

Comment: Sorry, I assumed when you said "given to me" you meant using the iTunes "gift this" button, not just straight copied. In that case I would suggest you either delete it, pay for it or stop complaining.

Comment: @Cawas im not entirely sure because all the apps i have are free or purchased and linked to my account.  i have never experienced an app "telling me to update."  i have seen apps that require me to have a current version of iOS on my phone before installing, or i have seen that an update is available when i open up the app store, but i've never had an app tell me to update it.

Comment: Now I noticed, this would better fit as a comment as it doesn't answer at all my question! :P

Answer (score 1):

It is possible you had run into whatever is described here (the comment 9:09AM on 3-05-2010 and further): http://www.tuaw.com/2010/03/04/paid-app-upgrades-coming-to-app-store/2#comments

So seems clear iPhone checks the installed apps vs iTunes store but when you click update all and it asks for the updated app, iTunes says "nuh-uh! you did not purchase this one, i am not signing/certifying bundle for you"

Comment: This is what happens, but on the device itself - not on iTunes. Now the question persists... How to disable those warnings? What if I just don't want to update / upgrade?